# why am I getting a black texture?

Tags: c++, opengl

The main.cpp is like this:

```
#include <mLibs/mainIncludes.hpp>
// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;


// camera
Camera camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f));
float lastX = SCR_WIDTH / 2.0f;
float lastY = SCR_HEIGHT / 2.0f;
bool firstMouse = true;

// timing
float deltaTime = 0.0f; // time between current frame and last frame
float lastFrame = 0.0f;



int main(){
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    #ifdef __APPLE__
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    #endif

        // glfw window creation
        // --------------------

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    std::string vShaderPath = fUtils::absFileRelCurDir("shaders/main6.vs"); //define path 
    std::string fShaderPath = fUtils::absFileRelCurDir("shaders/main6.fs"); //define path
    Shader ourShader(vShaderPath.c_str(), fShaderPath.c_str(), "MAIN_OBJECT_SHADER");

   float vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,

    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,

    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f
};

    unsigned int VBO, VAO,texture{};
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(5* sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);



    unsigned char* data{};
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    //absFileRelCurDir gives absolute path of file relative to current directory
    data = stbi_load(fUtils::absFileRelCurDir("resources/steelWood.png").c_str(),&width,&height,&nrChannels,0);
    if(data){
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,width,height,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }else{
        std::cout<<"STBI.H::Image Loading Failed"<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    stbi_image_free(data);


    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        // per-frame time logic
        // --------------------
        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        processInput(window);
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture);
        ourShader.use();
        ourShader.setMat4fv("model", model);
        ourShader.setMat4fv("view", view);
        ourShader.setMat4fv("projection", projection);
        ourShader.setInt("mTexture", texture);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);//set parameters or use glDrawElements
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;

}   


void processInput(GLFWwindow *window){

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(FORWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(BACKWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(LEFT, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(RIGHT, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_Q) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(UP, deltaTime); 
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_E) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(DOWN, deltaTime); 
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}


// glfw: whenever the mouse moves, this callback is called
// -------------------------------------------------------
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    if (firstMouse){
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    float xoffset = lastX - xpos;
    float yoffset = ypos - lastY; // reversed since y-coordinates go from bottom to top

    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    camera.ProcessMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset);
}

// glfw: whenever the mouse scroll wheel scrolls, this callback is called
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    camera.ProcessMouseScroll(yoffset);
}
```

The vertex shader is as:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 aNormal;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec2 mTexCoord;

void main(){

    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);
    mTexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

And the fragment shader is as:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 result;


in vec2 mTexCoord;
uniform sampler2D mTexture;

void main(){

    result = texture(mTexture, mTexCoord);

}
```

I assure you the classes used above are working as expected since I had already tested them some time before. There's no error while compiling and linking the shaders as well. I've also tried a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290938/sampling-from-a-texture-in-opengl-is-black) [other](https://community.khronos.org/t/texture-is-not-rendering-renders-black/76796) similar posts, but it seems they aren't addressing the issue.
If anyone could please point out if possible what mistake I am causing that made me waste my entire day, it would be really really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Just for reference purposes, the rest of the code is here:
mainIncludes.hpp  :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/include/glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <mLibs/mainPrototypes.hpp>
#include <mLibs/shader.hpp>
#include <mLibs/fileUtils/fileUtils.hpp>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <vector>
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <libs/stb_image.h>
#include <mLibs/camera.hpp>
#include <mLibs/genLamp.hpp>
```

The `shader` class used above:

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <glad/include/glad/glad.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>


#define SHADER 0
#define SHADER_PROGRAM 1

class Shader{
    private: unsigned int ProgramID{};
    private:unsigned int vShaderID, fShaderID;
    private: static const unsigned int infoLogSize = 1024;
    private:char infoLog[infoLogSize]{};
    private:int success;//indicates shader compilation/linking success
    private:std::string tag;

    public: Shader(){
        std::cerr<<"SHADER_H::Shader class- no_args_constructor::Warning::Constructor invalid"<<std::endl;
    }
    public: Shader(const GLchar* vertexPath, const GLchar* fragmentPath, std::string mTag);
    public: void use();
    public: void setBool(const std::string &name, bool value);
    public: void setInt(const std::string &name, int value);
    public: void setFloat(const std::string &name, float value);
    public: void setFloat3f(const std::string& name, float value1, float value2, float value3);
    public: void setFloat3fv(const std::string& name, glm::vec3 valueVector);
    public: void setMat4fv(const std::string& name, glm::mat4 mat4Matrix);
    public: int compileShader(unsigned int& shaderID, 
                            GLuint shaderType,const GLchar* const * shaderCode);
    public: int compileProgram(std::vector<unsigned int> shaderIDs);
    public: int compileProgram(unsigned int& programID, 
                            std::vector<unsigned int> shaderIDs);
    void setVec3fv(const std::string& name, glm::vec3 valueVector);
    void setVec3fv(const std::string& name, float x, float y, float z);
    void setVec4fv(const std::string& name, glm::vec4 valueVector);
    void setVec4fv(const std::string& name, float x, float y, float z, float w);

    public: int checkError(unsigned int ShaderID, int checkType, GLuint shaderType=GL_VERTEX_SHADER){
        switch(checkType){
                case SHADER:
                    glGetShaderiv(ShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
                    if(shaderType == GL_VERTEX_SHADER){
                        if(!success){
                            glGetShaderInfoLog(ShaderID, infoLogSize, NULL, infoLog);
                            std::cout<<"SHADER.H::VERTEX SHADER::"<<tag<<":: SHADERS COMPILATION::FAILED!"<<std::endl;
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }else if(shaderType == GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER){
                        if(!success){
                            glGetShaderInfoLog(ShaderID, infoLogSize, NULL, infoLog);
                            std::cout<<"SHADER.H::FRAGMENT SHADER::"<<tag<<"::SHADERS COMPILATION::FAILED!"<<std::endl;
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }
                    std::cout<<"SHADER.H::SHADERS::"<<tag<<"::SUCCESS::SHADERS COMPILED:: SUCCESS!"<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case SHADER_PROGRAM:
                    glGetProgramiv(ShaderID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
                    if(!success){
                        glGetProgramInfoLog(ShaderID, infoLogSize, NULL, infoLog);
                        std::cout<<"SHADER.H::SHADER PROGRAM::"<<tag<<"::SHADER PROGRAM LINKING::FAILED!";
                        return -1;
                    }
                    std::cout<<"SHADER.H::SHADER PROGRAM::"<<tag<<"::SHADER PROGRAM LINKING::SUCCESS!"<<std::endl;
                    break;
            }
            return 1;
    }

    public: unsigned int getProgramID(){
        return this->ProgramID;
    }

};

Shader::Shader(const GLchar* vertexPath, const GLchar* fragmentPath, std::string mTag){
    std::string vertexCode;
    std::string fragmentCode;
    std::ifstream vShaderFile;
    std::ifstream fShaderFile; 
    tag = mTag;

    vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit|std::ifstream::badbit);
    fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit|std::ifstream::badbit);

    try{
        vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
        fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
        std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
        vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
        fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();

        vShaderFile.close();
        fShaderFile.close();
        /*convert stream to string*/
        vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
        fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();

    }catch(std::ifstream::failure e){
        std::cout<<"SHADER.H::"<<tag<<"SHADER FILES NOT SUCCESSFULLY READ::FAILED!"<<std::endl;
    }

    const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
    const char* fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();

    compileShader(vShaderID,GL_VERTEX_SHADER, &vShaderCode);
    compileShader(fShaderID,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, &fShaderCode);
    compileProgram(std::vector<unsigned int>{vShaderID,fShaderID});


}

int Shader::compileShader(unsigned int& shaderID,
                 GLuint shaderType,
                 const GLchar* const * shaderCode
            ){
    shaderID = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    glShaderSource(shaderID,1 , shaderCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shaderID);
    return this->checkError(shaderID, SHADER, shaderType);
}

int Shader::compileProgram(std::vector<unsigned int> shaderIDs){
    return this->compileProgram(this->ProgramID,  shaderIDs);
}

int Shader::compileProgram(
    unsigned int& programID,
                   std::vector<unsigned int> shaderIDs){

    programID = glCreateProgram();
    for(auto eachShaderID:shaderIDs){
        glAttachShader(programID, eachShaderID);
    }
    glLinkProgram(programID);

    /* OK to delete shaders after linking*/
    glDeleteShader(vShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(fShaderID);

    return this->checkError(programID,SHADER_PROGRAM);

}

void Shader::setBool(const std::string& name, bool value){
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(this->getProgramID(), name.c_str()),(int)value);
}

void Shader::setInt(const std::string& name, int value){
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(this->getProgramID(), name.c_str()),value);
}

void Shader::setFloat(const std::string& name, float value) {
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(this->getProgramID(), name.c_str()), value);
}

void Shader::setFloat3f(const std::string& name, float value1, float value2, float value3){
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(this->getProgramID(), name.c_str()), value1, value2, value3);
}

void Shader::setFloat3fv(const std::string& name, glm::vec3 valueVector){
    this->setFloat3f(name, valueVector.x, valueVector.y, valueVector.z);
}

void Shader::setVec3fv(const std::string& name, glm::vec3 valueVector){
    this->setFloat3fv(name, valueVector);
}

void Shader::setVec4fv(const std::string& name, glm::vec4 valueVector){
    glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(this->getProgramID(), name.c_str()), 
        valueVector.x, valueVector.y, valueVector.z, valueVector.w);
}

void Shader::setVec4fv(const std::string& name, float x, float y, float z, float w){
    this->setVec4fv(name, glm::vec4(x, y, z, w));
}

void Shader::setMat4fv(const std::string& name, glm::mat4 mat4Matrix){
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(this->getProgramID(), name.c_str()), 
                        1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mat4Matrix));
}

void Shader::use(){
    glUseProgram(this->getProgramID());
}

#endif
```

the `fUtils`  used above:

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* defines FILENAME_MAX */
#include <string>

#ifndef FUTILS_H
#define FUTILS_H

#ifdef WINDOWS
    #include <direct.h>
    #define GetCurrentDir ::_getcwd
    std::string pathSeperator("\\");
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    #define GetCurrentDir ::getcwd
    std::string pathSeparator("/");
 #endif

namespace fUtils{
    std::string getcwd(){
        char mCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];
        GetCurrentDir(mCurrentPath, sizeof(mCurrentPath)); 
        std::string currentPath(mCurrentPath);
        return currentPath;
    }

    std::string absFileRelCurDir(std::string filePathRelCurDir){
        return std::string(getcwd()+pathSeparator+filePathRelCurDir);
    } 
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A texture sampler in a shader has to be set to the index of the texture unit it should read from, not to the texture handle. See [OpenGL Wiki: Sampler](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Binding_textures_to_samplers)

Since your active texture unit is unit 0 (`glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);`), you have to replace

```
ourShader.setInt("mTexture", texture);
```

to

```
ourShader.setInt("mTexture", 0);
```

Comment: I am very fortunate that forums exist in this day and age. thanks a lot mate